# HTML5 video filling up client hard drive using IE9-11 in kiosk mode on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, kiosk

I am building a slideshow in a browser that auto-rotates through content of an intranet's RSS feed. Some of this content is video. If a slide happens to be video, it fills the screen and then plays the video for X seconds or the full length of the video, whichever is shorter before moving on to the next slide. Video's can be any MB size.

The content of the slides is fetched on page load and then refreshed (if needed) every 5 minutes.

The computer is never turned off or re-started unless there is a power outage or upgrades are needed. In testing this all worked great.

Then we put it live and started IE in kiosk mode.

Now the each time a video gets cycled through it creates a new cache file. This results within a full hard-drive within a few days. We do have control of the client machines but would prefer not to set up some kind of batch file. We have tried setting the preferences in IE for cache size and even setting things to no-cache but it doesn't seem to do anything for this issue.

The following is an example of how the code works for the video embed. I have tried variations on this in vanilla javascript as well but it made no difference for the video playback issue and JQuery actually turned out to be more performant at moving the element around the page so it's all JQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: SOMEURL,
    dataType: 'xml',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (xml) { 
      $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
         var slideIndex = $this.index();
         var videoId = 'video_' + slideIndex;
         var videoSrc = $this.find('enclosure').text();

         var vidAttribs = {
            'id': videoId,
            'class': 'js-video',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'controls': '',
            'preload': 'auto',
            'type': 'video/mp4',
            'src': videoSrc
         }

         var video = $('<video />').attr(vidAttribs);
         $('body').append(assembledElements);
      });
      xml = null;
    },
    timeout: 5500,
    error: function (req, status, err) {
        console.log("Whoops. I can't load the feed at" + feedUrl + " - Type of error:", status, err);
    }

});
```

Later on in the code the video gets played when it becomes the top slide on the stack:

```
video.play();

var stopVidAsNeeded = setInterval(function () {
    if (video.currentTime >= videoPlayTime) {
        video.pause();
        video.currentTime = 0;
        clearInterval(stopVidAsNeeded);
    }

}, 500);
```

My question is this:

Do you see any holes in the logic or is there anything in the embed code I can change that will smarten IE up in this regard?

Again, it seems to only affect IE in kiosk mode. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't underestimate the amount of cleanup that takes place when you browse away from a page. If you are NEVER navigating away from the page, it's entirely possible that some resource is not being released.

Comment: you can simply schedule disk cleanup to run more often, not ideal, but better than a BAT file